# what is ''Size'' parameter size unit,In Set parameter Method?

Tags: c#, mysql

```
`parameter = command.CreateParameter ("Num",DB.adSmallInt,  DB.adParamInput,2, anyValue)`
```

I want to know in Case of the type was

> DB.adSmallInt

and the

> size = 2

will the size be 
2 Byte ? 
or 
2 Bit ? 
in which unit it will be Configured?

Comment: The chances are the `size` parameter will be ignored since an adSmallInt *is* two bytes in size.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_comm_createparameter.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the size parameter will be ignored since an adSmallInt is two bytes in size,
and is getting converted to smallint in SQL server side.